# A choice between two books

Tags: time-series, references, finance

Can anyone please advise which of the following books I should read:

- *Statistics and Data Analysis* by Rupert
- *Analysis of financial time series* by Tsay.

I am interested in applying the theory and mathematics to stock and commodity data. Which one the above books is better given my purpose? My degree is in mathematics but I have knowledge of basic statistics, time series and R.

Comment: Or which one to start first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started reading both the books and after going through first three chapters, I find Tsay's book to be better as it was easier to understand (for me at least). BUT this is my opinion.